# How do I get ergoemacs-mode set to default without "Symbol's function definition is void: ergoemacs-mode" error

Tags: ergoemacs

Running windows 8.1, package intallation went fine.

Enabling with `M-x ergoemacs-mode` works like a charm, but doing this every time I start up Emacs gets quite tiresome.

adding

```
(setq ergoemacs-theme nil) ;; Uses Standard Ergoemacs keyboard theme
(setq ergoemacs-keyboard-layout "us") ;; Assumes QWERTY keyboard layout
(ergoemacs-mode 1)
```

to `~/.emacs` as advised [here](https://ergoemacs.github.io/) gets me the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/Users/UserName/AppData/Roaming/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: ergoemacs-mode

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I don't have a clue about how to do this debug mode properly (get No Match in return), but in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Debugging-a-customization-file.html) I found how to evaluate each expression. using `C-x C-e` Evaluating first two of the added lines give me `nil` and `"us"`, and evaluating the last line enables ergoemacs-mode.

in my `~/.emacs` I also found this block of code:

```
 '(ergoemacs-ctl-c-or-ctl-x-delay 0.2)
 '(ergoemacs-handle-ctl-c-or-ctl-x (quote both))
 '(ergoemacs-ini-mode t)
 '(ergoemacs-keyboard-layout "us")
 '(ergoemacs-mode nil)
 '(ergoemacs-smart-paste nil)
 '(ergoemacs-theme "standard")
 '(ergoemacs-theme-options nil)
 '(ergoemacs-use-menus t)
```

Neither changing `'(ergoemacs-mode nil)` to `(ergoemacs-mode 1)`, removing that line OR changing `'(ergoemacs-mode nil)` to `(ergoemacs-mode 1)` and 
removing the other 3 lines works.

Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to emacs.stackexchange!  Where is your `(package-initialize)` or `(require 'ergoemacs-mode)` statements to load the library at issue **before** you start trying to use something within the library?  Did you follow the quick-start guide?:  https://ergoemacs.github.io/

Comment: I didn't know I needed one (I'm quite new to Emacs and I don't dare call myself a programmer yet)

Comment: I gave you a plus+1 to your reputation because you documented the issue sufficiently well enough for everyone to see what may be the problem.  I think everyone who uses Emacs has had to figure out how to call `package-initialize` and/or `require` at one time or another -- it is part of the ritual baptism when joining the Emacs cult following.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that. I still can't get it to work though... ' Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/Users/Jan-Rienk/AppData/Roaming/.emacs':

Wrong type argument: listp, t'

Comment: You may find it helpful to add `(setq debug-on-error t)` to the top of your `.emacs` file, save, and restart Emacs.  It may help you see more details regarding where the problem is.  I keep debugging enabled all the time, but feel free to remove it or comment it out once you track down the problem.

Comment: Without looking into this closely, my suggestion would be to use Customize to set those option values. And make sure your init file loads your `custom-file` before you try to enable the mode. (If you don't have a `custom-file` then make sure you enable the mode only after the `custom-set-variables` expression that Customize adds to your init file.)

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I tried a fresh install and didn't forget to initialize and require this time.